# "You will be the President himself." — The noun "President" is not someone but something. Then why is "itself" not used instead of "himself"?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns, gender, genderless-pronouns, animacy

the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 1497 ([the link](https://img.onl/RGj63z)):
**(1)** *You will be the President **himself***.
Am I right that "himself" means the gender of the subject "you" is masculine?

my variant:
**(2)** *You will be the President **herself***.
Am I right that "herself" means the gender of the subject "you" is feminine?

my variant:
**(3)** *You will be the President **themselves***.
Am I right that "themselves" means the gender of the subject "you" is not defined?

---

my variant:
**(4)** *You will be the President **itself***.
Is (4) correct?

my logic:
The noun "President" is not someone but something. Therefore, we must use "itself".
That is, by my logic, (1), (2) and (3) must be all incorrect and (4) must be the only one which is correct.
Why is my logic wrong?

---

Update:
I wrote "*the noun "President" is not someone but something*" — because in [wordreference.com's thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-qualify-to-achieve-the-standard-of-skill-that-is-necessary-for-being-something-someone.3684517/post-18788521), they said "*the job title is 'the thing'*".

Comment: This is an odd sentence. Changing "himself" to "itself" doesn't fix it, but your instinct that it doesn't quite work is right.

Comment: Looking at Joe Biden, it seems very clear that he is someone, and not something.

Comment: Can you please give an example of an inanimate *object* that has been a president? There is an apocryphal story that Caligula, a Roman emperor, [made his a horse a senator](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incitatus#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20story%20that,a%20joke%20about%20doing%20it.) which is perhaps the most well-known "myth" of an animal holding a political position. In that case, you could justify telling the horse "**You will be a senator yourself**” Oh, no... Wait, in the 3rd person "**The horse itself will be a senator**" that works.

Comment: Besides "themselves", why not also "oneself"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I added an update into the end of my question. Could you tell me please my train of thoughts is clear now or I need to clarify something else?

Comment: Would you really use "it" as the pronoun with President? Can you give an example of that? (The thread you cite isn't about pronouns, it's random people discussing an unrelated topic on a board anyone can post on.)

Comment: @StuartF You're asking: "_Would you really use "it" as the pronoun with President? Can you give an example of that?_" — since I'm not a native English speaker, I can't answer these questions. I asked about "itself" only based on what's explained on the link I gave. But you said it's "an unrelated topic" — could you explain to me please why it's unrelated?

Comment: Dialogue in a **play or movie**: Ah, you must be the president himself. Do come in." "itself" and "themselves" just don't work here.

Comment: The image link is no longer working (or, temporarily over quota). It should either be uploaded directly to this site; or, since it's an image of text anyway, just quoted fully. It would be good for some longer quotes form the WordReference link to be included for the same reason: links have a tendency to go bad, making things less useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between the example in the WordReference thread and the example in CGEL is that one is referring to a *role*, and the other to an *identity*.

As a *role*, we can talk about "being a president" - "Joe Biden is a president", "Paul von Hindenburg was a president". In this case, "a president" is "something that you are" - we can also say "Joe Biden is a man", "Joe Biden is a Democrat", etc.

However, this doesn't mean that *Joe Biden* is "something", because Joe Biden is an *identity*. We can refer to the same person as "the 46th President of the USA", or in the right context simply as "the President". In this case, "the president" is clearly "someone", not "something".

When we're using a pronoun to refer back to "the president", we are using it in the "identity" sense - we are talking about *Joe Biden* or *Paul von Hindenburg*, not *the role of head of state*. That means we need to use "himself" or "herself"; or, in case we're not sure or want to recognise a non-binary gender identity, "themselves" (or "themself", which some purists dislike but is quite common colloquially).

We don't use "it" when referring to people, so we would say "Joe Biden himself" and "the President himself"; never *"Joe Biden itself" or *"the President itself".

So, we have:

> He has the ability to be *something*
>
> What is *it* he has the ability to be?
>
> To be a president

But:

> I think *someone* is coming
>
> Who is coming?
>
> The President *himself*

---

It's worth adding that the CGEL example has been contrived to make a point about theoretically possible grammar, which is why it sounds a bit awkward. To imagine some context for it, let's say John and Mary are being given parts in a play:

> "Mary, you will be the president's wife" said the director.
>
> "And who will I be?" asked John.
>
> "You will be the president himself!"

In this case, "you" and "himself" are actually referring to different people: "you" refers to John, the actor; "himself" refers to "the president", the person John will pretend to be in the play. This is the point CGEL is making with the example.

This also allows us to answer this question:

> Am I right that "himself" means the gender of the subject "you" is masculine?

No: we can imagine if Mary was given the role of the president, and identifies as a woman; but the *character being played* was a man (maybe it's a play about John F Kennedy). "You" would refer to Mary, and in the third person it would be "She will be the president himself".

Comment: The question is not whether "himself" is used correctly, it is, what the OP wants to know if their variant `4. You will be the President itself.` is correct and adds `Why is my logic wrong?` You've not mentioned **it** at all.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I hoped the reasoning was clear: "Joe Biden himself" and "the President himself"; not \*"Joe Biden itself" and `*"the President itself". I've edited to make that more explicit. I've also thought of a way to include "it" in the "ability to..." example; hopefully it's not too convoluted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As for "the question is not whether himself is used correctly", I disagree. The OP says "(1), (2) and (3) must be all incorrect" - so an answer saying they are correct is directly answering that part of the question.

Comment: I see, you are right,  I had forgotten that part.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments suggest the original sentence sounds odd. I don't entirely agree: awkward maybe, but "You will be the President himself" certainly comes across as grammatical to me, as it did to the writers of the CambridgeGEL, who describe it as a "possible" use of *himself.* "You will be the President herself" is correctly formed as the feminine equivalent.

- "(3) You will be the President themselves": This is a less common wording. "Themselves" as a pronoun of undefined gender is mainly used when the identity of the person is not known (in contexts like "Whoever borrowed the book will have to return it themselves"; an alternative that can be heard is "themself").  Normally, when you say "You will...", you know the identity and gender of the person that you're talking to. You would use "himself" in this sentence if the person is male, and "herself" if the person is female. Of course, when discussing pronoun use and gender in English, it is worth mentioning that some people request to be referred to with the pronouns *they/them/theirs...* because of their gender expression (e.g. some but not all [nonbinary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/singular-nonbinary-they-is-or-they-are) people prefer this set of pronouns). In that case, the reason for using "Themselves" would be because that is the specific pronoun that person has said to use. Other people might request to be referred to specifically with pronouns like "himself" or "herself", or alternatives. In those circumstances and in general, the choice of pronoun would depend on the specific person that you're talking about. "Themselves" is not just a simple substitute for "himself" or "herself".
- "(4) You will be the President itself": This does not sound right. Unfortunately, "the noun 'President' is not someone but something" is simplistic to the point of being erroneous. Depending on the context, "President" could be either someone or something. We can use the wording "be something" with people to describe what they do or are, but it doesn't mean that the word "President" itself always is always used with neuter pronouns like *it*: it normally isn't.

Comment: I'm confused. For example, if we have the sentence "_He is the President / a doctor / a driver_", then is "_the President / a doctor / a driver_" something or someone? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii: That question isn't straightforward to answer because it depends on the context. The use of pronouns in English isn't based on inherent grammatical properties of nouns. The same thing/noun can be "someone" or "something" depending on the point of view that you're taking towards it

Comment: "President/doctor/driver" etc all refer to a person in that sentence.  I don't agree that this isn't straightforward.  It seems very straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

1. **You** *will be* ***the president himself** (herself / themself (singular) / themselves (plural))*

The gender of "you" is not predefined, it could be a man (*he*),
woman (*she*), intersex or gender fluid (*they* or *it* if that is someone's preferred pronoun). The CGEL example  above is highly unusual inasmuch as the pronoun "you" appears to conflict with the noun phrase "the president himself". I don't think there would be many native speakers who would say or write this statement. Perhaps a political journalist or a politician might say that to a candidate.

---

Public positions or job titles are held by people, not things or animals.

Nonetheless there is an apocryphal story about Caligula, a Roman emperor, who [made his a horse a senator](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incitatus#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20story%20that,a%20joke%20about%20doing%20it.). It is perhaps the most well-known "myth" of an animal holding a political position, in which case, you could justify telling the horse:

> (a) **You yourself** *will be a senator*
> (b) **You** *will be a senator* ***yourself***

If you were telling a friend, you could say

> (c) ***He himself** will be a senator*.
> (d) ***He** will be a senator **himself***

No. The pronouns "you" and "he"  work for humans too because the [reflexive pronoun](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/reflexive-pronouns) for "he" is "himself" and the reflexive pronoun for "you" is either  "yourself" (singular) or "yourselves" (plural). But we can use the 3rd person singular pronoun "it" in this way

> (e) ***The horse itself*** *will be a senator*
> (f) *The horse will be a senator* ***itself***.

All these versions work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Worth pointing out that, according to CGEL, *You will be the President himself*. is an utterance where third person himself cannot have you as antecedent. So, he is saying it is a no-go. Sometimes, their writing is so arcane. My problem is that I do not even understand what it means and actually think it's nonsense.