# "He is the President / a doctor / a driver." — How to define whether "the President / a doctor / a driver" is something or someone?

Tags: animacy

My question (from [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346416/you-will-be-the-president-himself-the-noun-president-is-not-someone-but-s/347558#comment675949_347558) under one of ell.stackexchange.com's answers):

> If we have the following sentence:
> **(1)** "*He is the President / a doctor / a driver*."
> Then, is "*the President  a doctor / a driver*" something or someone in it?

the answer I got there:

> That question isn't straightforward to answer because it depends on the context. The use of pronouns in English isn't based on inherent grammatical properties of nouns. The same thing/noun can be "someone" or "something" depending on the point of view that you're taking towards it.

I'm very interested in this topic.
Could you explain it to me please in more detail?
In what context is "*the President / a doctor / a driver*" something and in what someone?
How to define whether a noun is something or someone?

---

Update №1:
I think "the President", "a doctor", "a driver", etc. can be used to refer to things because of the following information:

My question (from [one](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-qualify-to-achieve-the-standard-of-skill-that-is-necessary-for-being-something-someone.3684517/) of forum.wordreference.com's threads):

> One of the definitions of the verb "to qualify" from [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qualify):
> to qualify — to achieve or have the standard of skill, knowledge, or ability that is necessary for doing or being **something**, or to cause someone to reach that standard:
> **(2)** *James hopes to qualify as a nurse practitioner*.

> Why is it written "being something"?
> Is, for instance, "a nurse practitioner" (from the example given) something?
> I thought "a nurse practitioner" is someone but not something.

the answers I got there:

> A nurse practitoner is a 'something' because it refers to the job (or in this case the qualification) , not the person doing it.

> The job title is 'the thing' The person achieves the skills to have the ability to fulfil the job description.

> You just need to accept that in English a person can be 'a + the name of a job" I am a teacher, he is a lawyer, but that these jobs/positions are 'things' not 'people.'

---

Update №2:
Dear users who think this question is a duplicate of ["You will be the President himself." — The noun "President" is not someone but something. Then why is "itself" not used instead of "himself"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346416/you-will-be-the-president-himself-the-noun-president-is-not-someone-but-s), please explain why you think so because otherwise without your explanation this kind of suggestion doesn't make any sense to me and the message box about the question being duplicate (at the beginning of the post) just looks like a spam to me.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, nor do I understand the comment you linked to. It's nonsense IMHO  President, doctor, and driver are words that we use to refer to people, not things.

Comment: Titles are things, the title of "King" is something. The person who holds that title is someone,  a person. Example: ["Highness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highness) **It** is typically used with a possessive adjective: "His Highness", "Her Highness" … (Wikipedia)

Comment: "You will be the President itself." the pronoun "you" is for people, the reflexive form is "yourself". If you wanted to use "itself" you need to reword it. The title (King) itself can only be inherited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["You will be the President himself." — The noun "President" is not someone but something. Then why is "itself" not used instead of "himself"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346416/you-will-be-the-president-himself-the-noun-president-is-not-someone-but-s)

Comment: @Marie-Lou No, it doesn't - it is the source of the current question.

Comment: @BillyKerr I added an update to my post. Please tell me if it's clear now?

Comment: "Who is Joe Biden?" "He is the President of the USA" (that is the position he holds). "Who's that man over there?" "He is the President" (identifying an individual).

Comment: You said something which supported your variant which used the reflexive pronoun "itself"; I quote "*my logic:
**The noun "President" is not someone but something**. Therefore, we must use "itself*"." In this post you ask "in what context is "the President …" something and in what someone?” The posted answers attempt to explain this not difficult concept to grasp. You have to explain why you believe you can  refer to a president/doctor/driver/teacher/engineer etc. etc. as *it*.

Answer (score 1):

If **he** is the President, or a doctor, or a driver, then these all refer to a person.

Contrast with "The Presidency", which is a role. "It is the Presidency".

But no similar term exists for "doctor".

And note that dummy pronouns "it" is used even when referring to a person "Who is it? / It's Michael."

This is all really a discussion about nothing. I can't see any difficulty in understanding "My brother is a teacher" or "My brother works as a teacher" regardless of your internal classification of "teacher".  The semantic content of "teacher" is not specific to English.

Comment: The trick here is that president can be person or a job...Just silly, though, I agree.

Answer (score -2):

> In what context is "the President / a doctor / a driver" something and in what someone?
> Is it possible to define whether a noun is something or someone?

I think the comment that you have quoted is inaccurate and vague - I would ignore it.

The occupational nouns of "the President / a doctor / a driver, etc" reflect the gender of the holder.

They can be neuter when the meaning is "holding/doing the job/position of the President / a doctor / a driver, etc." or the title of president / a doctor / a driver

*Nobody would want to be [the] president of Ruritania - **it*** (being president of Ruritania) *is something that ends in assassination.*

*I am president but* **it** (the job/position) *is temporary.*

*He was a driver, but **it*** (driver - title of a job) *was not a job he enjoyed.*

*His title was "Doctor" but **it** was honorary only.*

Comment: What do you mean, they 'reflect the gender of the holder'?

Comment: "The **president** is a busy man, **he** can't see you now." The **doctor** is in theatre - **she**'s treating an emergency. The **driver** is a trained chimpanzee - **it**'s very careful."

Comment: No, it's the pronouns you have used that reflect gender, not the nouns themselves.

Comment: I am not sure what you are arguing here. "President" will have a pronoun that reflects the holder's gender. "President" in the senses of "being president" will have a neuter gender.

Comment: You said "The occupational nouns... reflect the gender of the holder", which they don't **unless** they are matched with a pronoun.